# Unable to establish connection between on IaaS Sql server and Function App in azure

Tags: java, sql-server-2012, azure-function-app

Unable to establish a connection between `IaaS Sql` server and function App. I am getting SSL Key exception

I am trying to run a function in azure functions that were created in java. I establish the DB connection with the help of `sqljdbc4.jar`. This code runs successfully on a local machine, but when I try to run it on function app it throws below issue.

```
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: \"java.security.ProviderException: java.security.KeyException: Key does not exist.\r\n\
```

Expected to establish a connection between `IaaS SQL` server and azure function.